# Custom Rake Seed File (Rails 4.2.1 Ruby 2.2.3) - Loops more times than once and creates duplicate entries in database

Tags: database, sqlite, ruby-on-rails-4, rake-task, seeding

I have set up a custom rake seed task to populate my database. My rake task is set up to loop through an array of arrays once (upon executing) and populate the database with said data. For some reason, the rake task seems to be running five times when I run the task once.

Also, every position looped through created an additional nil value record in the database.

After staring at my code I can't reason these two issues are happening. Any help is much appreciated!

```
**testdata.rb**

questions = [
   ["What is the supreme law of the land?\n1) the Ley of the Land\n2) the Article of Law\n3) the Constitution\n4) Article One of the Constitution", "3", "The Constitution is the \"supreme law of the land\" and establishes the basic principles of the US govt. It lists fundamental rights for people living in the USA.", "Version1", "English"],

   ["The \"supreme law of the land\" is not the Constitution.\n1) True\n2) False", "2", "The Constitution is the \"supreme law of the land\" and establishes the basic principles of the US govt. It lists fundamental rights for people living in the USA.", "Version1", "English"]
]

questions.each do | body, correct_answer, explanation, version, language |
   Question.create(subject_id: 3, body: body, correct_answer: correct_answer, explanation: explanation, version: version, language: language, active: true)
end
```

---

```
**test.rake**

namespace :db do
  namespace :seed do
    Dir[File.join(Rails.root, 'db', 'seeds', '*.rb')].each do |testdata|
      task_name = File.basename(testdata, '.rb').intern    
      desc "Load the seed data from db/seeds/#{task_name}.rb"
      task task_name => :environment do
        load(testdata) if File.exist?(testdata)
      end
    end
  end
end
```

---

```
**Output in SQLLITE ActiveRecord query after running rake task**

MacbookAir $rake db:seed:testdata
MacbookAir $rails c
Running via Spring preloader in process 23953
Loading development environment (Rails 4.2.6)
2.2.1 :001 > Question.all.map{|s| puts s.body}
Question Load (0.4ms)  SELECT  "questions".* FROM "questions"  ORDER BY "questions"."id" DESC LIMIT 10
What is the supreme law of the land?
1) the Ley of the Land
2) the Article of Law
3) the Constitution
4) Article One of the Constitution
The "supreme law of the land" is not the Constitution.
1) True
2) False
What is the supreme law of the land?
1) the Ley of the Land
2) the Article of Law
3) the Constitution
4) Article One of the Constitution
The "supreme law of the land" is not the Constitution.
1) True
2) False
What is the supreme law of the land?
1) the Ley of the Land
2) the Article of Law
3) the Constitution
4) Article One of the Constitution
The "supreme law of the land" is not the Constitution.
1) True
2) False
What is the supreme law of the land?
1) the Ley of the Land
2) the Article of Law
3) the Constitution
4) Article One of the Constitution
The "supreme law of the land" is not the Constitution.
1) True
2) False
What is the supreme law of the land?
1) the Ley of the Land
2) the Article of Law
3) the Constitution
4) Article One of the Constitution
The "supreme law of the land" is not the Constitution.
1) True
2) False
=> [nil, nil, nil, nil, nil, nil, nil, nil, nil, nil]
```

Answer (score 0):

That might be old data left over in your db... you might want to try

`db:reset`

> The rails db:reset task will drop the database and set it up again. This is functionally equivalent to rails db:drop db:setup.

[rails guide](http://edgeguides.rubyonrails.org/active_record_migrations.html#resetting-the-database)

Comment: ran rake db:reset and still ended up with the same results: 5 entries for each index position and one nil value for each entry in the db table